# Pegar a media de um campo em tabela de relacionamento many to many Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-eloquent

Tenho um relacionamento Many to Many e na tabela de relacionamento o campo "value".
Como faco para trazer a media desse campo usando o Eloquent?

Exemplo:

```
Tabela A
a_id
```

Tabela de Relacionamento

```
a_id
c_id
value
```

Tabela C

```
c_id
```

A query no mysql seria essa:

```sql
SELECT sentis_feelings.feeling_id, avg(sentis_feelings.value) 
FROM sentis_feelings 
GROUP BY sentis_feelings.feeling_id;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Exemplo com Eloquent**

**Obs:** *a melhor solução para o seu problema está no final desse exemplo, mas, eu fiz questão de mostrar pelas tabelas de muitos para muitos para que dependendo do caso pode ser usado, tranquilamente.*

***Tabelas***

```
CREATE TABLE `feeling` (
  `feeling_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feeling_descricao` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`feeling_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
---------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `sentis` (
  `sentis_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sentis_desc` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sentis_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
---------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `sentis_feelings` (
  `sentis_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `feeling_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `value` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sentis_id`,`feeling_id`),
  KEY `pkf1_idx` (`feeling_id`),
  KEY `pkf2_idx` (`sentis_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pkf1` FOREIGN KEY (`feeling_id`) 
   REFERENCES `feeling` (`feeling_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `pkf2` FOREIGN KEY (`sentis_id`) 
   REFERENCES `sentis` (`sentis_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

***Models***

```
//MODEL SENTIS
class Sentis extends Eloquent {
    public $table      = 'sentis'; 
    public $primaryKey = 'sentis_id';
    public $timestamps = false;    
    public function feeling()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Feeling','sentis_feelings', 'sentis_id','feeling_id')
                    ->withPivot('value');
    }
}
```

---

```
//MODEL FEELING
class Feeling extends Eloquent {
    public $table      = 'feeling'; 
    public $primaryKey = 'feeling_id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function sentis()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Sentis', 'sentis_feelings', 'feeling_id', 'sentis_id')
                    ->withPivot('value');
    }
}
```

***Eloquent Query***

o primeiro resultado traz o agrupamento pelo `feeling_id=1` (***model Feeling***), mas, esse ainda não traz todos, porque, para acessar o relacionamento sou obrigado a passar o `feeling_id` `(find(1))`.

```
$resultado = Feeling::find(1)
    ->sentis()
    ->select(DB::raw('AVG(`value`) AS `Media`'))                    
    ->groupBy('feeling_id')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
echo $resultado[0]['pivot']['feeling_id']. ': '.$resultado[0]['Media'];
```

A segundo resultado é trazendo o agrupamento pelo `sentis_id=2` (***model Sentis***), acontecendo a mesma coisa do outro caso sou obrigado a passar `sentis_id` (`find(2)`).

```
$resultado = Sentis::find(2)
    ->feeling()
    ->select(DB::raw('AVG(`value`) AS `Media`'))                    
    ->groupBy('sentis_id')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
echo $resultado[0]['pivot']['sentis_id']. ': '.$resultado[0]['Media'];
```

***Melhores Soluções***

**1 )**

Para solucionar utilize, então um outro model `SentisFeeling` como código abaixo:

```
class SentisFeeling extends Eloquent {
    public $table      = 'sentis_feelings'; 
    public $primaryKey =  array('sentis_id', 'feeling_id');
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Sendo assim respondendo a sua questão com a mesma SQL da pergunta

```
$resultado = SentisFeeling::groupBy('feeling_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('`feeling_id`, AVG(`value`) AS `Media`'))
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

foreach ($resultado as $item) {
    echo $item['feeling_id']. ' - '. $item['Media'];
    echo '<br>';
}
```

**2 )**

Usando Query Builder como exemplo abaixo:

```
$resultado = DB::table('sentis_feelings')
    ->groupBy('feeling_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('`feeling_id`, AVG(`value`) AS `Media`'))
    ->get();

foreach ($resultado as $item) {
    echo $item->feeling_id. ' - '. $item->Media;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Obrigado amigao! Vou dar uma lida com calma na segunda feira e te dou um feedback! Abracos!

Comment: @SalloSzrajbman só não esqueça que se for útil fechar a sua questão, para que sirva para os demais usuários... e obrigado.

Comment: Claro! Amanha sem falta testo e falo! Obrigado!

Comment: Funcionando perfeito! Obrigado!