# Relacionamento muitos para muitos laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.4

Bom tentei ler a documentação e desenvolver este relacionamento porém não conseguir, na verdade preciso informar qual é o nome do do tipo do usuario. O modelo de banco de dados esta assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`MODELS` envolvidos

```
App\User
App\TipoUser
App\UserTipo
```

E no meu model esta assim:

**MODEL User**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

protected $table = 'user';
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
  protected $fillable = [
    'NmUser',
    'Email',
    'Senha',
    'CPF',
    'Celular',
    'DtNasc',
    'FlgTipo',
    'Rua',
    'Bairro',
    'Cidade',
    'UF',
    'CEP',
    'Num',
    'Comple',
    'FlgStatus',
    'DtPagamento',
    'DtVencimento'
];

protected $primaryKey = 'UserId';

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'Senha'
];

public function tipos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\UserTipo','user_tipouser', 'UserId','TipoUserId')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
}
```

**MODELO UserTipo**

```
<?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


 class UserTipo extends Model
 {
 use SoftDeletes;


protected $table = 'user_tipouser';
protected $fillable = [
    'UserId',
    'TipoUserId',
];

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

**MODELO TiposUser**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TiposUser extends Model
{
protected $table = 'tipouser';
protected $fillable = [
    'TipoUserId',
    'NmTipoUser',
    'DscTipo'
];

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\UserTipo','user_tipouser', 'TipoUserId','UserId')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
}
```

> Meus outros modelos não soube fazer

Em meu html estou fazendo assim:

```
 <td>{{ $user->tipos->tipos->DscTipo }}</td>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Relações:***

Quando se faz uma relação muitos para muitos na documentação está estipulado da seguinte forma:

```
$this->belongsToMany('relacao',  
                     'nome da tabela pivot', 
                     'key ref. model classe atual', 
                     'key ref. outro model classe relação');
```

no seu caso já havia um erro por não ter estipulado o segundo paramento com o nome da tabela que faz a relação. Outra coisa que faltou é informar que deseja trazer os dados das colunas `created_at` e `deleted_at`

Logo abaixo os dois métodos que serão configurado nas classe `User` e `TipoUser`:

***Model:***

`User:`

```
public function tipos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\TipoUser','user_tipouser', 'UserId','TipoUserId')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

`TipoUser:`

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','user_tipouser', 'TipoUserId','UserId')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Também em relação ao seu `HTML` tem que verificar o seguinte agora é uma lista de valores como exemplo abaixo:

```
@foreach($user->tipos as $t)
    <td>{{ $t->NmTipoUser }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Nesse [link tem a explicação](http://artesaos.github.io/howto/eloquent-many-to-may/) em um modelo muito prático observe como funciona e faça correlação com o seu. Outro [link exemplo do próprio Stackoverflow <sup>pt</sup>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23476/pegar-a-media-de-um-campo-em-tabela-de-relacionamento-many-to-many-laravel-eloqu/23500#23500) também muito bom para tirar as suas duvidas.

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [Eloquent - Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships)
- [Eloquent - Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many)
- [Eloquent ManyToMany - Relacionamentos Muitos para Muitos](http://artesaos.github.io/howto/eloquent-many-to-may/)